# how to count number of present(status 1 means present) for each student and input beside each student profile under present column

Tags: php

[daily_attendances database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbKnn.jpg)

```
below is under crud_model

public function take_attendance()
    {
        $students = $this->input->post('student_id');
        $data['timestamp'] = strtotime($this->input->post('date'));
        $data['class_id'] = html_escape($this->input->post('class_id'));
        $data['section_id'] = html_escape($this->input->post('section_id'));
        $data['school_id'] = $this->school_id;
        $data['session_id'] = $this->active_session;
        $check_data = $this->db->get_where('daily_attendances', array('timestamp' => $data['timestamp'], 'class_id' => $data['class_id'], 'section_id' => $data['section_id'], 'session_id' => $data['session_id'], 'school_id' => $data['school_id']));
        if($check_data->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($students as $key => $student):
                $data['status'] = $this->input->post('status-'.$student);
                $data['student_id'] = $student;
                $attendance_id = $this->input->post('attendance_id');
                $this->db->where('id', $attendance_id[$key]);
                $this->db->update('daily_attendances', $data);
            endforeach;
        }else{
            foreach($students as $student):
                $data['status'] = $this->input->post('status-'.$student);
                $data['student_id'] = $student;
                $this->db->insert('daily_attendances', $data);
            endforeach;
        }

        $this->settings_model->last_updated_attendance_data();

        $response = array(
            'status' => true,
            'notification' => get_phrase('attendance_updated_successfully')
        );

        return json_encode($response);
    }



public function get_presentcount_by_student_id($student_id="",$status ="") {
        
        $checker = array(
        
            'student_id' => $student_id,
            'status'    => 1
        );
        $presentcount_by_student_id = $this->db->get_where('daily_attendances', $checker);
        return $presentcount_by_student_id->num_rows();
    }
```

under the list.php where it shows the student name and the number of days present for each student.The code is below but it does not count number of presents for each student.It still remains 0

```
<td>
            
                
              <?php  echo $this->crud_model->get_presentcount_by_student_id($student['user_id'],'status');?>
              <br>
              
            </td>
```

Student detail list shown in table format
[student_detail_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd7HJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$count=DB::select("SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM 'your-table-name' where status = 1 ")->get();
```

and you can access this by `$count[0]->num`

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter framework.I assume the above code is for laravel framework after researching

Comment: ok you can use this query in pure php in order to count the present status

Comment: meaning do I have to just input the query inside the list.php? replacing <?php  echo $this->crud_model->get_presentcount_by_student_id($student['user_id'],'status');?>

Comment: where do i input the above query into my code.can assist?thanks

Comment: I still cant get it.any idea?pls thanks